# ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Object

Tags: java

Getting this message:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Here's the Java code:

```
  public List<String> retrieveData() {
       String queryString = " " +
              "SELECT o.rootOrganisation.idOrganisation " +
              "FROM Organisation o " +
              "ORDER BY o.idOrganisation " ;
       Query query = getFilteredCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);

       List<Object[]> listOfObject = query.list();
       List<String> listOfDTO = new ArrayList<>();

       //Loop through an array of objects
       for (Object[] org : listOfObject ) {
           for (int i = 0; i < org.length; i++) {
               listOfDTO .add((String) org[i]);
           }
       }
       return listOfDTO;
   }
```

When returning the listOfDTO, getting class cast exception.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO.  On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Can you show us where you called this method? Or how was ```listOfDTO``` used?

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace in your question.

Comment: What is the type of the `idOrganisation` column?

Comment: Use instanceof before typecasting

Comment: You did not select multiple columns, so as far as I know, the returned result set would be a list of `String`.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of responsiveness.

Comment: Can you please post the results returned by the query.. I think it should a list of Objects instead of array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `List<Object[]> listOfObject = query.list()` line.  At least one of the elements returned by `query.list()` is a `String` and not an object array.

Comment: This line would not throw an exception though. `Object[] org : listOfObject` is likely the one throwing exception.